# Splitting a column of Datetime type in Py and used the append function to add the resulting columns to the dataframe, not working

Tags: pandas, split, python-datetime

- Dataset is a fictitious bike rental activity.
- Columns include started_at and ended_at, of datetime.

**# I have renamed the columns with intent to split start and end datetime type columns, as date and time**

```
df.rename(columns = {'started_at':'DateTimeA','ended_at':'DateTimeB', 
  }, inplace = True)
print(df.columns)`
```

**#Process the split, create columns and add columns to the dataframe**
​

```
df1 = df.DateTimeA.str.split(expand=True)   
 df1.columns= ['Start_Date', 'Start_Time']
 df2 = df.DateTimeB.str.split(expand=True)   
 df2.columns= ['End_Date', 'End_Time']
 df = df.append(df1)
 df = df.append(df2)
 df`
```

The columns add up but the start and end time in date and time columns sometimes don't match the initial value: no value instead of the value specified in the initial columns.

My objective is to compute trip durations (time), and cyclicality of the activity( date).

I have used stack overflow to try this ;-))...someone please, help :-((

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

# create a sample dataset
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'started_at': ['2022-01-01 10:10:05', '2022-01-02 12:04:01', '2022-01-03 14:01:20'],
        'ended_at': ['2022-01-01 10:25:10', '2022-01-02 16:03:04', '2022-01-03 16:10:10'],
    }
)

# convert started_at and ended_at to datetime format
df['started_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['started_at'])
df['ended_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ended_at'])
```

```py
# split datetime into date and time
df['Start_Date'] = df['started_at'].dt.date
df['Start_Time'] = df['started_at'].dt.time

df['End_Date'] = df['ended_at'].dt.date
df['End_Time'] = df['ended_at'].dt.time

# drop the original started_at column
df = df.drop(columns=['started_at', 'ended_at'])
```

---

However, you don't need to split the datetime into date and time in order to compute the duration.

```py
# calculate the duration in hours and minutes
duration = df['ended_at'] - df['started_at']
df['duration_hours'] = (duration.dt.total_seconds() // 3600).astype(int)
df['duration_minutes'] = (duration.dt.total_seconds() % 3600 // 60).astype(int)
df['duration_seconds'] = (duration.dt.total_seconds() % 60).astype(int)
```